# Debugging search queries sent to Azure search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

We are using Azure Search for a client site created in Sitecore, however there is a problem with some of the search queries.  I would like to know if there is a way in Azure where I can view the queries that are submitted to Azure search?  I'm looking for the quickest and easiest solution that is as near to real time as possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SiteCore Experience Cloud from the Azure marketplace and have direct access to the Azure Search service it uses, you can enable monitoring to collect telemetry to an Azure blob storage account, among others.  This copies the logs to JSON files.  They include the raw queries sent to the server.  There is also a PowerBI content pack for Azure Search you can use to wade through and understand this information a little more easily.

More info on collecting Azure Search telemetry is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-monitor-usage#how-to-export-logs-and-metrics

More info on the PowerBI dashboard for Azure Search is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-connect-to-azure-search

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Mike
Azure Search Team

Comment: so there i no such thing as a kibana for azure search? What if you want to write your and test your queries before you actually implement it. The search explorer azure search provides is limited and from my understanding you cant use power bi for that either